# DataReader throws 'Specified cast not valid' when reading the result of dividing two long decimals in Oracle

Tags: sql, vb.net, oracle, decimal, datareader

I've got the following example in VB (.NET 4.0, VS2010, Oracle 10g)

```
Dim objDb As New OracleOdp("my_connection_info.udl")
        Dim sql = <sql>
            SELECT 'okay' As PoC, TO_NUMBER('47,3222404188609999999999999999999999') / TO_NUMBER('21,3222404188609999') FROM dual
        </sql>.Value
        objDb.SQL = sql
        Dim dr = objDb.Execute()
        dr.Read()
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Field count: {0}", dr.FieldCount))
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("First value (= 'okay'): {0}", dr(0)))
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Second value (throws cast error): {0}", dr(1)))
```

OracleOdp being a custom class to create a simple Oracle connection.

Upon executing this sample, I get an error at the last line as I try to read what's in the second column of my DataReader, saying "Specified cast is not valid" with the following stack trace (Source: Oracle.DataAccess):

```
   à Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDataReader.GetDecimal(Int32 i)
   à Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDataReader.GetValue(Int32 i)
   à Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDataReader.get_Item(Int32 i)
   à HelpPls.Module1.Main() dans C:\Users\xxxx\Documents\TempHelp\HelpPls\Module1.vb:ligne 24
   à System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
   à Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
   à System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   à System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   à System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   à System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

I'm forced to use the Oracle.DataAccess DLL version 4.112.2.0.

The error happens every time that I try to divide a decimal with another, but I can't possibly truncate nor round the numbers as they're used elsewhere (not in VB, mind you!) in conditions.

How to make it work?

Comment: Could it be your use of a comma (`,`) as the decimal mark?  [TO_NUMBER Function](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_number.php) shows using a period (`.`) in the example.

Comment: I forgot to say it, but the request is not the problem. It works fine in PL/SQL Developer!

Comment: It appears that ADO.NET is trying to map the Oracle data type to a `Decimal` and the actual value doesn't represent a valid `Decimal`.  Try getting the value as a `Double` specifically and see if that works.  The data reader should have a `GetDouble` method or the like.

Comment: @TnTinMn -- I think that's a localization thing.  When we get data from Europe, their commas and periods are transposed.  It drives me batty

Comment: @Hambone, I understand that.  My point was that the documentation I referenced, indicates an optional language code to define proper parsing; it implies that the default expects a period as the decimal mark.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you would normally do this would be to use the `OracleDecimal` data type.  I apologize I don't know VB.net, but in the spirit of demonstrating this, here is a simple example in C#:

```
OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(<your query>, conn);

OracleDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
reader.Read();

OracleDecimal d1 = reader.GetOracleDecimal(1);
```

From here, you could get the decimal value simply by:

```
decimal d2 = d1.Value;
```

or more succinctly, both statements in one:

```
decimal d = reader.GetOracleDecimal(1).Value;
```

All that said, the precision in the result is too much for a decimal, and this will throw an error.  You really need a double precision to make this work.  Any of these should work for you:

```
double d = reader.GetOracleDecimal(1).ToDouble();
```

or, better, as you won't lose precision

```
double d = reader.GetDouble(1);
```

which is pretty much what @jmcilhinney said in his comment.

Comment: I'm getting back to work in a few hours, I'll keep you updated ASAP! Thank you very much  for your answer in the meantime!

Comment: It finally works ! Thank you very much to you two ! :)

Comment: It works for me too. A few days without dealing with this. Thanks!